# Smooth curves in button

Tags: c#, user-interface, button

I want to create a toggle button similar to [this](http://marcangers.com/animated-switch-togglebutton-style-in-wpf/) or to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/794577/Windows-Forms-ToggleButton). Animation does not matter to me. I tried to create a toggle button with the code below. However I cannot get it to be smooth curves and edges. I am using windows forms application and a total beginner in C# UI design.

My question is that is it possible to make the curves smooth, or it will still stay like this? I imported the code in the second link, but still the button did not appear smooth.

I also used -

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

Here is full code for the button -

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace MyWorkspace
{
    public class ToggleButton : Control
    {
        #region variables        
        public enum ButtonState { ON, OFF };
        private ButtonState toggleState = ButtonState.OFF;
        private Rectangle contentRectangle = Rectangle.Empty;
        #endregion

        #region properties
        public ButtonState ToggleState
        {
            get
            {
                return toggleState;
            }
            set
            {
                if (toggleState != value)
                {                    
                    toggleState = value;
                    Invalidate();
                    this.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public ToggleButton() : base()
        {
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(50, 25);
            this.MaximumSize = new Size(50, 25);
            contentRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
            this.BackColor = Application.RenderWithVisualStyles ? Color.Azure : this.Parent.BackColor;
        }        

        // Draw the large or small button, depending on the current state.
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;            

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, contentRectangle.Y, contentRectangle.Height, contentRectangle.Height);            

            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            int d = this.Height;
            gp.AddArc(contentRectangle.X, contentRectangle.Y, d, d, 180, 90);
            gp.AddArc(contentRectangle.X + contentRectangle.Width - d, contentRectangle.Y, d, d, 270, 90);
            gp.AddArc(contentRectangle.X + contentRectangle.Width - d, contentRectangle.Y + contentRectangle.Height - d, d, d, 0, 90);
            gp.AddArc(contentRectangle.X, contentRectangle.Y + contentRectangle.Height - d, d, d, 90, 90);

            this.Region = new Region(gp);

            Rectangle ar2 = new Rectangle(rect.X, contentRectangle.Y, (rect.X + rect.Width / 2) + contentRectangle.Right, contentRectangle.Height);

            LinearGradientBrush br;
            Rectangle ellipse_rect;
            if (toggleState == ButtonState.ON)
            {
                br = new LinearGradientBrush(ar2, Color.FromArgb(0, 127, 234), Color.FromArgb(96, 174, 241), LinearGradientMode.Vertical);                
                ellipse_rect = new Rectangle(contentRectangle.Right - (contentRectangle.Height -2),
                    contentRectangle.Y, contentRectangle.Height - 4, contentRectangle.Height);                
            }
            else
            {                 
                br = new LinearGradientBrush(ar2, Color.FromArgb(120, 120, 120), Color.Silver, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);                
                ellipse_rect = rect;
            }

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, ar2);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Gray, 2f), ellipse_rect);
            LinearGradientBrush br2 = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.White, Color.Silver, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(br2, ellipse_rect);   
            Color c = this.Parent != null ? this.Parent.BackColor : Color.White;
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(c, 2f), gp);            
        }        

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (toggleState == ButtonState.ON)
                toggleState = ButtonState.OFF;                            
            else
                toggleState = ButtonState.ON;

            Invalidate();
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post an image of what your solution looks like, but from what you have described I would guess you do not have anti-aliasing enabled. [Here is a MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t6sa8s9(v=vs.110).aspx) about how to enable anti-aliasing. If you are going to be changing the look of many controls in your application, you may want to look into [Windows Presentation Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268(v=vs.110).aspx) or the new [Universal Windows Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide).
In contrast to Windows Forms, both WPF and UWP are vector based interface layers that are designed using XAML. Because of the way WPF and UWP implement their designing system, it is very easy to completely customize the look and feel of your application. In addition both platforms have built in functionality for animations.